# Verifying user credientials with libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

My goal with the code below is to use curl to determine if the provided `url` and `uidPwd` are enough to connect to the provided URL. If the url is wrong, `curl_easy_perform` returns `CANNOT_RESOLVE_HOST`. However, if the url is ok the call returns `CURLE_OK` regardless of whether or not the user provided valid credentials. I understand why this is happening, curl is connecting to the provided url regardless of whether or not the credentials are correct (if they aren't correct instead of providing the requested resource it returns what amounts to "authentication failed"). My question is, is there any way to know whether the authentication failed using nothing more than the return code of 'curl_easy_perform'? If not, what would be the easiest way to solve this problem? I don't want to go to the trouble of parsing the returned HTTP.

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, uidPwd);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_ANY);

        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &BJConnection::writefunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);

        returnCode = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
        assert(returnCode == CURLE_OK);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this using libcURL alone. However, I am using PugiXML to parse the result returned by libcURL and have figured out a workaround to check the validity of the provided credentials using Pugi. Here's the solution:

```
        returnCode = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);

        pugi::xml_document doc;
        // We will only be able to load the result into Pugi XML if libcURL
        // returns XML. HTTP is returned in the event of a login error
        pugi::xml_parse_result loginSuccess = doc.load_string(s.ptr);
        if (returnCode != CURLE_OK) {
            BJTHROWGEN("Error connecting to Bamboo server. cURL return code: " +
                returnCode);
        } else if (!loginSuccess) {
            BJTHROWGEN("Could not login to Bamboo using the provided credientials.");
        }
        else {
            // Success
            m_isConnected = true;
        }
```